# Python sum if nth element is same in nested list (list of lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Python sum if nth element is same in nested list (list of lists)

```
my_list1=[['John',2,'goals',4],['Robert',5,'hike',3],['Julia',6,'paid',2],['John',4,'fine',6],['Robert',3,'loop',44],['Julia',1,'cool',33],['Kris',6,'wild',4],['Kris',8,'word',67]]
```

Result

```
my_list1=[['John',2,'goals',4],['Robert',5,'hike',3],['Julia',6,'paid',2],['John',4,'fine',6],['Robert',3,'loop',44],['Julia',1,'cool',33],['Kris',6,'wild',4],['Kris',8,'word',67]]
result = {}
for i in my_list1:
    name = i[0]
    if name in result:
        result[name][1] += i[1]
        result[name][2] += i[3]
    else:
        result[name] = [name, i[1], i[3]]
my_list2=[]
[my_list2.extend([v]) for k,v in result.items()]
print (my_list2)
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
x =[['John',2,'goals',4],['Robert',5,'hike',3],['Julia',6,'paid',2],['John',4,'fine',6],['Robert',3,'loop',44],['Julia',1,'cool',33],['Kris',6,'wild',4],['Kris',8,'word',67]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
xx = (df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index().as_matrix())
s=[]
for i in xx:
    for j in i:
        s.append(j)
new = []
for i in range(0, len(s), 3):
    new.append(s[i:i+3])
print(new)
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `(for j in i):j` supposed to mean?

Comment: Your question isn't clear and so is the (unformatted) code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary where the key is the name and value is a list of the sums.

```
result = {}
for i in my_list1:
    name = i[0]
    if name in result:
        result[name][1] += i[1]
        result[name][2] += i[3]
    else:
        result[name] = [name, i[1], i[3]]
my_list2 = result.values()
```